# Is this comparison inconsistent (or is there another problem)?

Tags: c++, sorting, iterator, comparator

The code below seg faults on my mac; but, works fine (without even valgrind errors) on Linux.

I suspect that the comparison function is giving an inconsistent result; but, I can't see how.

(I have a feeling I'm going to feel foolish when somebody points it out :)

For context:  This is a student's code.  I know there are much better ways of coding this, I'm just stumped as to why it's wrong.

```
using namespace std;

using Point = std::pair<double, double>;
using PointVector = vector<Point>;
extern PointVector cluster1;

bool sortComparison(const Point &point1, const Point &point2) {

  if(point1.first < point2.first)
    return true;
  else if(point1.first > point2.first)
    return false;
  else if(point1.second < point2.second)
    return true;
  else if(point1.second > point2.second)
    return false;
  else
    return true;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  cout << "In" << endl;
  std::sort(cluster1.begin(), cluster1.end(), sortComparison);
  cout << "Out" << endl;

}
```

Comment: The problem is the last case: If they are equal, you say `point1` is less than `point2`.

Comment: `else if(point1.second > point2.second)
    return false;
  else
    return true;` is equivalent to simply `return !(point1.second > point2.second);`

Comment: Also, you might write `std::tie(point1.first, point2.second) < std::tie(point1.first, point2.second);`. That is assuming you're not _actually_ using `std::pair` in your real code, in which case you wouldn't need any of this - `std::pair` has `operator<` already...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comparison function for `std::sort` should return true if the first argument is **less** than the second (`a < b`), however you are returning true if it is equal (`a <= b`, due to `else return true;`). This probably breaks the implementation of `std::sort`.

Comment: Yup. It should have been obvious :)

Comment: Although, I find it interesting that the gcc/Linux implementation of `std::sort` can handle this error.

Comment: @Zack undefined behaviour doesn't mean "this breaks". The most insidious symptom is "this behaves how I (mistakenly) think it should, right up to when it doesn't"